# you wouldn't have otherwise had

Tags: sentence-construction

> It gives you opportunity **you would not have otherwise had**.

It is a conditional sentence, but without "if". The meaning of the last part is fathomable to me. And now my questions are:

> 1- ***Why was not "if" used?***
>   2- ***What is the role of "otherwise" from grammatical standpoint?***

Comment: It's not quite grammatical as it is. Could you cite the exact text and its source?

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty https://books.google.com/books?id=sGDdFZ-vIi8C&pg=PA409&lpg=PA409&dq=%22would+not+have+otherwise+had%22&source=bl&ots=a_CH1MjKCO&sig=ACfU3U2nYM4aYy1XkMn0rJEiLs0lHTMQOw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj3rKqcsOvoAhVHyYUKHXCOCbEQ6AEwAXoECAsQJQ

Comment: OK, that's a little different.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty which part is different. do you meant the first part. If so, if I change it to "could have went through", it will be correct?

Comment: see my answer, just posted. The only problem was the comma, which left the parts unconnected. I guess by "go through" you mean "consume" or "eat"? Or "use up"?

Comment: The quote is not copied correctly, it is barely grammatical while the original talks about "creating opportunities". Worse of all, the OP's line should have quoted the full sentence.

Answer (score 1):

In the work cited in your comment, "Justice Oliver Wendell Holmes: Law and the Inner Self", by By G. Edward White, the phrase appears like this:

"...creating opportunities he would not have otherwise had."

This is an example of conditional perfect, with the condition implied by the word "otherwise", and with the negation "not".

[Wikipedia "Conditional perfect"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_perfect)

For your proposed sentence, you should start with a capital letter and remove the comma, leaving
"You can go through this food you would not have otherwise had."'

**An added note, to keep up with the editing of the OP:**
[American Heritage Dictionary "otherwise"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=otherwise)
The definition under conjunction is "if not". This means an implied "if" clause. The rest of the clause is whatever the "otherwise" negates; as Kate Bunting noted, "if he had not become a judge", or in your original example, if the food had not been supplied.

Comment: I improved my question, thanks for your attention

Comment: You would not have had the opportunity **if** circumstances had been different. In the phrase from the book, he would not have had those opportunities if he had not become a judge.

Comment: @Kate Bunting I added a definition of "otherwise" to clarify.